# On n'a donc pas eu le choix d'utiliser le sifflet d'urgence

Tags: sens, expressions

*Le pire meilleur ami* d'Alexandra Larochelle :

Théo raconte à Azalée, sa meilleure amie, que Louis-Philippe et lui sont venus à la plage pour faire une balade en canot. Ils sont arrivés au milieu du lac, Théo a voulu embrasser LP, mais le canot a chaviré, et ils se sont retrouvés dans l'eau. Donc, d'après le contexte, LP et Théo ont appelé à l'aide.

> — On n'a donc pas eu le choix d'utiliser le sifflet d'urgence. (1)

Je ne comprends pas la construction *ne pas avoir le choix de + infinitif*. Pourquoi cette phrase signifie *On n'a pas eu le choix, c'est pourquoi on a utilisé le sifflet d'urgence* ?

Je comprendrais la phrase (1) dans le sens de *On n'a pas pu utiliser le sifflet d'urgence*, mais d'après le contexte, c'est le contraire : ils l'ont utilisé.

Voici la phrase suivante :

> Mais bon, en attendant qu'on **vienne nous secourir** dans le lac glacial,
> on s'est peut-être repris pour le baiser manqué.

Comment: De mon point de vue, c'est une anglicisme, un calque approximatif de *We had no choice but to*.

Comment: @XouDo Peut-être. Mais pourquoi alors ne pas garder "que" dans _On n'a donc pas eu d'autre choix **que** d'utiliser le sifflet d'urgence_ ? Ou traduire alors comme _On n'a donc pas eu d'autre choix **mis à part** / **mais** d'utiliser le sifflet d'urgence_.

Comment: Je comprends, mais le **que** alourdit la phrase alors même qu'elle est très compréhensible en l'état (Pour moi, pas de confusion avec : *On n'a pas pu utiliser le sifflet d'urgence* qui serait formulée différemment).

Answer (score 2):

Je comprends la phrase comme toi. Elle signifie bien qu'ils n'ont pas pu utiliser ce sifflet, ce qui semble improbable au vu de la situation, ces sifflets étant attachés au gilets de sauvetage qu'ils devaient porter sur eux.

Il s'agit peut-être d'une faute d'inattention pour :

> On n'a donc pas eu d'autre choix que d'utiliser le sifflet d'urgence.

Comment: J'ai trouvé un [fil](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/vous-navez-pas-dautre-choix-que-de.3929824/) semblable. _Vous n'avez (pas) d'autre choix **que** de boire…_